# facebook login issue iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

So here is the problem.Steps to reproduce:
Facebook SDK 3.2,any iPhone Device

```
1.Login to the Facebook account in the iPhone Setting.
2.Launch the Scrumptious application.
3.Click on login button.
4.Accept the Permission.
5.Remove the application from the Device.
6.Remove the app from the Facebook App setting from the Accounts setting of ur Facebook.
7.Reinstall the application.
8.Clik on the login button. 
Now here is the issue.It goes to the "Profile" Screen and then logs out automatically prompting `Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.`
```

Why does this happen?How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The way to overcome it is to just login again (after the failure)!

What happens is that iOS doesn't know the user has removed the app from the Facebook website, so it issues the app a cached token. When the app tries to use this token to make a request, it will fail (since the token is now invalid). The SDK will see this error, and close your session, but it will also tell iOS to invalidate its cache. So when you log in again, it will contact Facebook for a new token.

Comment: So it that case,Can't I remove or invalidate the cached token from the app programmatically?

Comment: The issue is that it's not cached in your app, it's cached in iOS, so your app doesn't even know about it. The only way to know for sure is to fail once, and then reopen the session. 

This is similar to a scenario where your app may be authorized, but if the user removes your app from Facebook, the next request your app issues will fail, and you have to close the session and reopen it (which will prompt the user again).